# Numbers doubling in SSRS Tablix

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that has pre-calculations using the OVER clause and when the data is displayed the numbers are exactly double what they should be.

So if I have 100 rows for a specific grouping I should see only a single instance of the OVER clause total.

Let's say letter id XXX has a total usage of 1000, when it displays in the tablix it reads 2000. There are no totals or sums in the tablix because my OVER has already taken care of it. I have several of these calculations in my SQL that I am using all over the report so I really don't want to calculate them in SSRS.

Here is an example.

Id - Letter Id - Volume - Total Volume

```
1 - AAA - 50 - 225
2 - AAA - 100 - 225
3 - AAA - 75 - 225
```

The total should be displayed as 225 but SSRS says it is 450. I am grouping by letter id and showing only one instance in my tablix and there are no sums or totals.

Comment: Can you post your query text?

Comment: Here is the over statement. The query is large.

(
  SUM(vcd.Display_Volume)
   
  OVER(PARTITION BY vcd.Letter_Id)
 )

Comment: Have you run the query directly and taken a look at the results? It seems likely to me that this is caused by having two rows for every id in your query, rather than something in SSRS.

Comment: In SSMS everything looks good. I even put the results in Excel and it calculates as it should. I also tried to sum the volume by itself, bypassing the over total and it also doubled the total. The odd thing is it is doing it all over the report.I am going to take a closer look at my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I commented out one condition in the SQL which caused everything to double. The issue was not with SSRS.